# Reindexing fails after upgrading solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, solr4

I used sunspot_solr and sunspot_rails gem that integrates solr 4 from the following link..

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-sunspot/c6OVesLyaSI)

Now, when i try to reindex the existing documents, i get a status 500, Internal Server Error..

I removed solr directory and after bundle install, and gave the following commands

```
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
rake sunspot:solr:run
```

where am i going wrong? :/

when i tried to reindex in rails console, i got the following error...

```
when i tried reindexing in rails console, i got the following error..
```

RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>500,'QTime'=>10},'error'=>{'trace'=>'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:204)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:451)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:587)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:346)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:246)

Comment: please check the solr logs as well, the indexing request seems to be failing.

Comment: it seems that i am getting a null pointer exception....

Comment: can you post the logs ?

Comment: severe solrcore nullpointerexception and the same for solrdispatchfilter

Comment: when i tried reindexing in rails console, i got the following error..

Answer (score 0):

The stopwords were causing the problems... i had to do some changes in the schema.xml(as i used ngrams in my project) and fixed the stopwards problem.. now its working fine  :)